# Colour picker crashing intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fedora

I'm actually encountering this error on CLion, but I reproduced it in IntelliJ.  When I go into settings, to change the colour settings, when I press on the colour to open the colour picker, CLion freezes, then crashes.  On windows, it works fine and opens up the colour picker.  I get the same results on OpenJDK and on Oracle Java.  I couldn't test on java 7, because Oracle makes it hard to download.

The error log is [here](http://lpaste.net/2694207270811598848), but it's 1500 lines.

Comment: Where's the code in question?

Comment: You might just contact JetBrains. Their support has always been very responsive for me.

Comment: Are you using wayland?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of features related to the GUI does not work under Wayland yet and if an application fails to handle it correctly, it crashes.

As an workaround, you can log into your account with old X11 (choose GNOME on X in the login screen).

Comment: Thanks, using X fixed it.